# Update math equation using MathLive and Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, mathjax, mathjs

I have been struggling to use Vue and MathLive to handle typesetting randomly generated numbers and their squares. The function of the program is to generate a random integer from 1 to 35, calculate the square, and typeset it with MathLive. There are two buttons that add one to the integer or create another random one. I have no problem typesetting the initial value but when I create a different integer or add 1 the page, it never re-typesets. I am trying to implement this program as a component in Vue. Here is my MWE (component only):

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="problem">
    <p id="math">$${{num}}^2 = {{square()}}$$</p>
    <button @click="addOne">Add One</button>
    <button @click="randomInt">Random Number</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import math from 'mathjs'
import MathLive from 'mathlive'

export default {
  name: 'Problem',
  data: function () {
    return {
      num: math.randomInt(1,35)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    num: function () {
      console.log("Data changed");
      // this.renderMath();
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    console.log("Hello This is created!");
    this.renderMath();
  },
  beforeMount: function () {
    console.log("This is beforeMount");
  },
  mounted: function () {
    console.log("This is mounted!");
  },
  beforeUpdate: function () {
    console.log("This is beforeUpdate");
    this.renderMath();
  },
  methods: {
    addOne: function() {
      this.num++
    },
    randomInt: function () {
      this.num = math.randomInt(1,35)
    },
    square: function () {
      return this.num**2
    },
    renderMath: function (event) {
      this.$nextTick(function(){
        MathLive.renderMathInElement("math");
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
@import url("../../node_modules/mathlive/dist/mathlive.core.css");
@import url("../../node_modules/mathlive/dist/mathlive.css");
p {
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

Edit: To clarify when I load the page up, the initial value is typeset correctly using MathLive as shown below: [image]
Then after I click either the *Add One* or *Random Number* button, the program should generate a new value, calculate its square, and update that value on the screen as shown below: [image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `re-typeset`?

Comment: It means that mathlive should be called again and the equation should update and be displayed. I could not get it to display properly.

Comment: When you say `not get it to display properly` means? can you please make it more clear because I am confused.

Comment: The equation isn't properly rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems MathLive's DOM manipulation conflicts with Vue's virtual DOM, preventing Vue from patching the DOM with the updated text node.

A workaround is to apply a [`key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) to force the MathLive `p` element to be re-created when the `key` changes. We could use `num` as the key, since it changes with each button press:

```
<p :key="num">...</p>
```

The current watcher on `num` would need to be updated to call `renderMath()` to refresh the MathLive element:

```js
watch: {
  num() {
    this.renderMath();
  }
},
```

You should also consider making `square()` a computed property for [more efficient rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods):

```js
// script
computed: {
  square() {
    return this.num ** 2
  }
}
```

```html
// template
<p :key="num">$${{num}}^2 = {{square}}$$</p>
```

[image: Edit MathLive in Vue component]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `vue.js` [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) properties

```js
new Vue({
  name: 'Problem',
  data: function () {
    return {
      num: math.randomInt(1,35)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    num: function () {
      console.log("Data changed");
      this.renderMath();
    }
  },
  computed: {
     square: function () {
        return this.num**2;
     }
  },
  created: function () {
    console.log("Hello This is created!");
    this.renderMath();
  },
  beforeMount: function () {
    console.log("This is beforeMount");
  },
  mounted: function () {
    console.log("This is mounted!");
  },
  beforeUpdate: function () {
    console.log("This is beforeUpdate");
    //this.renderMath();
  },
  methods: {
    addOne: function() {
      this.num++
    },
    randomInt: function () {
      this.num = math.randomInt(1,35)
    },
    renderMath: function (event) {
      this.$nextTick(function(){
        MathLive.renderMathInElement("math");
      })
    }
  }
}).$mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs/dist/math.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathlive@0.26.0/dist/mathlive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span>$${{num}}^2 = {{square}}$$</span>
  <span id="math"></span>
  <button @click="addOne">Add One</button>
  <button @click="randomInt">Random Number</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried the code above and while it does make sense to use computed instead of a method, the program does not re-typeset the math on the page. The initial value is the one that is being displayed. Any idea on how to get that to work?

Comment: What did you expect from `MathLive.renderMathInElement("math");`? What exactly should be rendered in element? Provide example or picture. It's not clear to me.

Comment: I have expanded on my question to clarify the desired output. I hope it helps!